# C - Reading binary file returns zeros

Tags: c, buffer, fread

I am trying to read a sector (512 bytes) from a binary file. The path to the file is correct, and I'm opening it as a binary. But when I'm trying to **fread** those 512 bytes, my buffer just gets filled with zeros. What am I doing wrong?

*Code fragment from main(), some variable names are changed keeping the meaning*

*Function get_formatted_string is defined above this fragment and works absolutely fine with no errors nor memory leaks*

*Every required header is included above this fragment*

**UPD**: *The input file is guaranteed not to be filled with zeros*

**UPD**: added output of the fread return value

```
...
    FILE* in;
    in = fopen(args.filepath, "rb");
    if (in == NULL){
        perror(get_formatted_string("error: %s", args.filepath));
        return errno;
    }

    char* buf = malloc(512);
    size_t fread_res = fread(buf, 1, 512, in);
    printf("%zu\n", fread_res);
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++){
        printf("%02x", buf[i]);
    }
...
```

Code output:

```
0

                 (0)
0000000000000000 ... 00000
```

Comment: You didn't check the return value from `fread`. If it isn't `1` (the number of items of size 512 read) then there is no reason to display the buffer content. I suggest you swap the size and count arguments, catch the number of *bytes* read, and use that to iterate the display loop. `size_t bytes = fread(buf, 1, 512, in);`

Comment: @WeatherVane I've checked the return value in both cases, and it's 0 for both. What could be the reason of this issue?

Comment: @NotYourFox simple - the first 512 bytes of the file are zeroes.

Comment: @0___________ Checked multiple times (bless, hexdump). The input file is not zero-filled

Comment: @NotYourFox there are no miracles programming.

Comment: You read data into `test`, but print data from `buf`

Comment: @NotYourFox ***and it's 0 for both*** if `fread` returned `0` then it did not read anything :)

Comment: @0___________ But why can it become filled with zeros when I'm attempting to read it from my code? I don't see any sense in it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Oops, poor edit (no such thing in the code)

Comment: `printf("%li\n", fread_res);` -> `printf("%zu\n", fread_res);`.

Comment: @0___________ That's why I'm asking, what can cause such a problem

Comment: @0___________ Changed printf, still 0 on output

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: add `if(fseek(in, 0, SEEK_END)) printf("ERROR"\n); printf("%ld\n", ftell(in)); ` before read. It will tell you how long your file is :)

Comment: @NotYourFox Your code looks fine.  In all likelihood, the problem lies somewhere else.  Perhaps the file your program is reading is not the same file as the one you hexdumped.  (Not trying to insult you with this supposition; it's a mistake we've all made.)

Comment: It would be better to declare `unsigned char* buf`.  Also `printf("%li\n", fread_res)` is wrong; it should be `printf("%zu\n", fread_res)`.  (But I don't expect either of these issues do make a difference wrt the zeroes.)

Comment: @0___________ Zero... Starts to make sense

Comment: Now you have a lesson on how to try to debug your code. Do not look at the screen for hours simply add some additional code which will give you some additional information. Asking questions here basically will not teach you anything.

Comment: I'll try debugging my code deeper, I can't yet find the problem with the filepath or the file itself

Comment: @0___________ Ikr, I've tried to debug it via gdb, but could not figure out the problem for the first time, I'll try playing with the code a little bit more

Comment: I took your code fragment, gave it a `main() { ... }`, pointed it at a binary file, compiled it, ran it, and: it gave me the file's contents (verified with another hexdump program).  So I can confirm that your code fragment is fine, and the problem is that the file you're actually reading must either be empty, or has the first 512 bytes as 0, or some other problem external to your program.